# How to auto resize rows height using poi in java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, row

I'm using the poi libary in java for my application to put strings in an excel file.
The thing is some of my strings contains multiple lines and when put in a cell only some of the informations are visible as seen on the third column.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0tLg.jpg
I'm forced to double click on the cell to view the informations as they should be presented.
Is there a method I can use to make the informations to be like the last row of the third column?
Thanks in advance.
Edit: here is the code of the class that do the conversion job.

public class conversion {

```
String filename = "C:\\Users\\daoudi\\Desktop\\FactureTest.xls" ;
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");
HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow(0);


public conversion(List<String> nom , List<String> tel, List<String> abo, List<String> total) throws IOException{
    try{
        rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("Nom");
        rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("Telephone");
        rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Abonnements");
        rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("Total");
    //HSSFCellStyle aligned = workbook.createCellStyle();
    //aligned.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.VERTICAL_JUSTIFY);


        for (int i=0;i<nom.size();i++){
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i+1);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(nom.get(i));
            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(tel.get(i));
            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(abo.get(i));
            //cell.setCellStyle(aligned);
            cell = row.createCell(3);
            cell.setCellValue(total.get(i));
            //cell.setCellStyle(aligned);

    }

        sheet.autoSizeColumn((short)0);
        sheet.autoSizeColumn((short)1);
        sheet.autoSizeColumn((short)2);
        sheet.autoSizeColumn((short)3);
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Add your code in question.

Comment: did you try something like this ?
sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);

Comment: put sheet.autoSizeColumn.. before put data in the cells

Comment: Basil it's the first thing I tried but it seems to only work on the width, and not even perfectly.

Comment: @Frank same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below a working code example

```
try {
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Desktop\\ook.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
        String str = "111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111";
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

        Row row =  sheet.createRow(0);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        Cell cell1 = row.createCell(1);

            CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle(); 

            cell.setCellStyle(style); 
            cell.setCellValue(str); 

            CellStyle style2 = wb.createCellStyle(); 
            cell1.setCellStyle(style2); 
            cell1.setCellValue(str); 

            sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);

        wb.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Desktop\\ook.xls")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I write "str" at the first two columns at the first row .

The libraries im using are :

[image]

Result:

[image]

In addition , there is even **autowrap** you could use , an example below :

```
try {
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Desktop\\ook.xls"));
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
            String str = "111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111";
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

            Row row =  sheet.createRow(0);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

                CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle(); 
                style.setWrapText(true); 
                cell.setCellStyle(style); 
                cell.setCellValue(str);

            wb.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Desktop\\ook.xls")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Your code indeed does work with very long strings on one line, but the thing is my data is stored on multiple lines, and this code produce a very wierd result as you can see: http://imgur.com/a/kmAAx

Comment: I just saw your edit, the setWrapText made the job. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think that I've done exactly what is written here, and still the text flows out of the cell and the cell does't grow properly. Why am I facing this?

Answer (score 0):

This should make it:

Row row =  sheet.createRow(0);
row.setHeight(-1);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).